# How to update time zone information after government announced change?

Tags: r, timezone

Brazil abolished daylight saving in 2019. The announcement was made Apr 2019. https://time.is/time_zone_news/no_dst_in_brazil_in_2019

So all R installed before 2019 have incorrect daylight saving information stored. How do I update this information? Do I need to re-install?

```
as.POSIXlt("2019-12-15",tz = 'America/Sao_Paulo')$isdst
#returns 1 if R was installed before 2019 (tested in windows)
```

Comment: You should update R anyway if your installation is that old. However, AFAIK, R uses OS facilities for datetime conversions.

Comment: For windows, `OlsonNames` indicates dir is `file.path(R.home("share"), "zoneinfo")`. I updated the interested cities with newer version of R.

Comment: Not related to R: for pandas, update pytz package. I never thought I need to update packages in my data processing PC.